# PHP script is running in the terminal but throwing error in the browser in linux

Tags: php, linux, symfony, geckodriver

This script is running in terminal but when I run same script in browser using xampp server its throwing this error - Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

I am using symfony/panther PHP package.

```
<?php 

use Symfony\Component\Panther\Client;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer's autoloader

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$client = Client::createFirefoxClient('drivers/geckodriver',[
   '--proxy-server=http://50.201.51.216:8080',
   '--headless'
]);

$client->request('GET', 'https://example.com');

$html = $client->getInternalResponse()->getContent();

echo $html;

?>
```

Complete error log -

```php
Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:146 
Stack trace: 
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php(359): Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException('unknown error', 'Process unexpec...', Array) 
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(129): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) 
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/symfony/panther/src/ProcessManager/FirefoxManager.php(70): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://127.0.0....', Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities), NULL, NULL) 
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/symfony/panther/src/Client.php(117): Symfony\Component\Panther\ProcessManager\FirefoxManager->start() 
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/symfony/panther/src/Client.php(521): Symfony\Component\Panther\Client->start() 
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/symfony/panther/src/Client.php(273): Symfony\Component\Panther\Client->get('https://exampl...') 
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/index.php(19): Symfony\Component\Panther\Client->request('GET', 'https://exampl...') 
#7 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testcrawler/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 146
```

This script is working fine on windows, I have tried to change the web server user as the same user i am in terminal and also restarted the web server but getting same error, Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Are both PHP versions the same?

Comment: It throws `WebDriverException` which probably means that you are missing driver, that is installed on linux env but missing on windows. From [docs](https://github.com/symfony/panther) you need to install `chocolatey` and then rub `choco install chromedriver selenium-gecko-driver`. You are mixing platforms in your question. If you are running something on one platform\OS probably it won't give you the same result on other.)

Comment: PHP version is same on both

Comment: this script is working fine in windows but not working in linux.. geckodriver is installed in linux.. if i run this script in terminal it works but in browser its throwing error.

Comment: Ok, probably i was confused ) But nevertheless, driver which is located in `drivers` folder is there ? There is also another approach listed in the docs that could [help](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) you. Install the driver manually into the specified folder. Or, here is another step by step [approach](https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-geckodriver-for-selenium-in-linux/) to your case. Running `apt-get` or `apt` is not always a solution for everything. You need to be sure that driver itself is reachable in the code. And dont forget about permissions.